# What is the sense of Spring Repositories over EntityManager and/or Jpa Provider like Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, repository

I wonder what the "big advantage" of a one-to-one relationship Spring `Repository` is over the EntityManager (persistencecontext) and Transactionmanager (transaction demarcation) (and/or Hibernate. I don't know how they work together exactly in JPA).

Can you explain the advantage of `Repository`?

It seems very rigid because you have to extend the repository interface for every Aggregate in a Microservice environment at least. I don't know if you have to do this for simple `@Entity`s too.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we use a Repository to perform CRUD operations, and it establishes a connection between the program and database to retrieve data, and call it into the service environment to perform some functions, that's the reason why extends the repository in the service and @Repository is the indication that it is a repository.

Comment: ... as well as an EntityARepository (belonging to `EntityA`) to read from. Well, also, in order to configure an Event Store in Axon, which is the library in question where Spring Repositories are needed, well, I ask myself what the sense is in general of the repository-pattern. What tasks does it do when accessing the database? And compared to that, what does the repository-pattern do more than Hibernate when accessing the database through this en lieu of a Repository. Thank you very much ! Yours sincerly, vonSpotz :)